# Wrong position after filter

Tags: android

I have a problem with my application. Actually, I'm totally stuck. I have a list of countries with implemented clicklistener and searchview. In a situation when I click on a given element without searching the list, everything displays correctly and shows information about a given country. But when I search the list and click on the element, the application goes to the information about the **random** country. I dont know why this is happening. I have no error. Only a warning:
**W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection**

**MainActivity**

```
public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";
public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_REGION = "country_region";
public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_NATIVE_NAME = "country_nativename";
public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_NAME_LANGUGES= "country_namelanguages";



private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
private List<ModelJsona> dataArrayList;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();

}


private void initViews(){
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    loadJSON();
}

private void loadJSON(){
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://restcountries.eu/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    RequestInterface requestInterface=retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<List<ModelJsona>> call= requestInterface.getJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelJsona>>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ModelJsona>> call, Response<List<ModelJsona>> response) {
            dataArrayList = response.body();
            dataAdapter=new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),dataArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            dataAdapter.setOnitemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ModelJsona>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    search(searchView);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void search(SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            if (dataAdapter !=null)dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this,Details.class);
    ModelJsona click = dataArrayList.get(position);


    detailsIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_NAME,click.getName());
    detailsIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_REGION,click.getRegion());
    detailsIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_NATIVE_NAME,click.getNativeName());
    detailsIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_NAME_LANGUGES,click.getLanguages().get(0).getName());


    startActivity(detailsIntent);

}
```

}

**DataAdapter**

```
  private Context context;
private List<ModelJsona> dataList;
private List<ModelJsona> filtr;
private OnitemClickListener mListener;


public interface OnitemClickListener {
    void onItemClick (int position);
}

public void setOnitemClickListener (OnitemClickListener listener)
{
    mListener=listener;
}

public DataAdapter(Context context, List<ModelJsona> dataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.filtr= dataList;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.country_name.setText(filtr.get(position).getName());
    holder.country_region.setText(filtr.get(position).getRegion());
    holder.country_nativename.setText(filtr.get(position).getNativeName());
    holder.country_languagename.setText(filtr.get(position).getLanguages().get(0).getName());





}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filtr.size();

}


public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String charString = charSequence.toString();

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                filtr = dataList;
            } else {

                ArrayList<ModelJsona> listadoprzeszukiwan = new ArrayList<>();

                for (ModelJsona wyszukiwarka : dataList) {

                    if (
                            wyszukiwarka.getName().contains(charString) ||
                            wyszukiwarka.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            wyszukiwarka.getRegion().contains(charString) ||
                            wyszukiwarka.getRegion().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            wyszukiwarka.getNativeName().contains(charString) ||
                            wyszukiwarka.getNativeName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            wyszukiwarka.getTopLevelDomain().contains(charString))


                             {

                        listadoprzeszukiwan.add(wyszukiwarka);
                    }
                }

                filtr = listadoprzeszukiwan;
            }

            FilterResults wynikiszukania = new FilterResults();
            wynikiszukania.values = filtr;
            return wynikiszukania;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults wynikiszukania) {
            filtr = (ArrayList<ModelJsona>) wynikiszukania.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView country_name, country_region,  country_languagename,country_nativename;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        country_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        country_region = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_region);
        country_nativename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_nativename);
        country_languagename= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_languagename);


    itemView.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener !=null){
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        }
    }));


    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see that you get the position in filter list refer to different object with same position value in dataList because after filtering filter list become reference to result but still dataList hold all data.

you can replace itemView click listner by this:

```
   itemView.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener !=null){
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            String name = filtr.get(position).getName();
            for (int i=0 ; i <dataList.size() ; i++ ){
            if(name.equals(dataList.get(i).getName()){
            position = i; 
            break;
            }
            }
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me how can i do it ? (Unique identifier)

Comment: getAdapterPosition() returns the position of item in the new filtered list and you use it to get the item info from the list off all data you need to send the correct position you might do more functions when item clicked to get right position

Comment: Thank you, I am new in Android. Could you give me an example code of this function?

Comment: already i had updated my answer you can replace itemView click listner with my answer and check